# Python CouchDB/httplib - error: [Errno 61] Connection refused

Tags: python, couchdb, httplib2

Did any one get this error? Please advice! There seems to be some problem with httplib python library.

```
Python 2.7 (r27:82508, Jul  3 2010, 20:17:05) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

>>> import couchdb
>>> couch = couchdb.Server()
>>> couch.create("foo")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    couch.create("foo")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/couchdb/client.py", line 193, in create
    self.resource.put_json(validate_dbname(name))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/couchdb/http.py", line 405, in put_json
    status, headers, data = self.put(*a, **k)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/couchdb/http.py", line 384, in put
    return self._request('PUT', path, body=body, headers=headers, **params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/couchdb/http.py", line 419, in _request
    credentials=self.credentials)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/couchdb/http.py", line 239, in request
    resp = _try_request_with_retries(iter(self.retry_delays))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/couchdb/http.py", line 205, in _try_request_with_retries
    raise e
error: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

Comment: Are you sure that couch is running on the default port? Can you telnet to it?

Comment: It's not running. How can I start CouchDB on Mac OS X?

Comment: D'oh! My bad! It wasn't running! It Works now! Thx for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you behind a proxy ? check by doing:
python -c "import urllib; print urllib.getproxies()"